# Is there a way to page through tags being searched for?

Tags: feature-request, tags

So, I'm looking for a tag in order to add to my tags of interest. On this occasion, something to do with **console**.

I enter **consol** in the filter box, and see a number of them, I make note, oh there's a *windows-console* tag, but none of which seem appropriate, so I click the **Name** tab in the hopes I can just see all in alphabetical order.

But, it forgets that I filtered on *consol*, so no worries, just enter it again.

As I scroll down, I notice I no longer see the *windows-console* tag, and I'm searching around for a *Next Page* and cannot find *windows-console*.

So, thought I'd raise the concern here.

Comment: Never noticed that. The tag page is paginated until you input something to search.